# Xcode - cycle through open windows

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to cycle through open windows.  I quite often use this when I want to reference something in another file.  On windows this would typically be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but I can't find a way to do this in Xcode on a Mac.

Comment: This is what worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10506195/253938

Answer (score 54, accepted):

On a Mac you can cycle through **any** program's windows using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick)

On Xcode4 same command is achieved with  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>.

Comment: few extra shortcuts:
Cmd + Opt + Left/Right - cycle through history of opened files;
Ctrl + 1 - view list of history files
Ctrl + 2 - view list of methods in opened file

Comment: Nope. On a German keyboard you won't have fun with back tick. Cmd-</> (so far) does work on (almost) all apps.

Answer (score 4):

Basic MacOS stuff: ⌘` shift⌘`

See "system preferences>keyboard>keyboard shortcuts>Keyboard & text input" for all the juicy details.

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks! (for switching between Xcode instances, rather than windows in one instance)

Answer (score 3):

All Cocoa: ⌘< and ⌘> to cycle through application windows.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but for me it just opens the SchemeManager... Maybe it has to to with a German Keyboard?

Comment: @Tom No, it's broken with the american/international keyboard as well. I consider reporting this issue as a bug (though it's just one of many subtle UI bugs of Xcode).

Comment: All applications are equal. But some applications are more equal than others. - Steve Jobs

Comment: On Xcode 6.4 CMD+SHIFT+> works to cycle through open windows :)

Answer (score 3):

Open Preferences/Key Bindings and look at conflicts. You may find <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> to be in conflict. As mentioned by @Nikolai Ruhe <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> / <kbd>></kbd> should cycle through ALL app windows.

Once again: All applications are equal. But some applications are more equal than others. - Steve Jobs

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches from one application to another.
<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> switches from one window to another within an application.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Xcode 7.0.1 onwards, you can now use  CMD + ~. 
I spent a while to find out how to toggle between Xcode View Controller and the apple Documentation help I get upon CMD clicking.
This works !

Answer (score 2):

For people with German and possibly other non-US keyboards, the default key combination often do not work; for example, ⌘< doesn't work in many of Apple's own apps like Xcode or Numbers, Pages etc.

Even Apple's own suggestion of "Umschalttaste-Befehlstaste-Tilde (~)" here https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT201236 (in German!) doesn't work! This is probably because the tilde ~ is available only via a key combination itself on German keyboards.

My solution was to rebind the "Move focus to next window" shortcut to ⌘^. This works in all apps for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly what you're looking for, <kbd>F10</kbd> (or <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> depending on your keyboard setup), will show you all windows belonging to the open program.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 6.4 <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> works to cycle through open windows :)