# How to jump forward/backward from Xcode split window?

Tags: xcode, window, split

I used to split my Xcode window to 4 sub windows (not popup). I wonder if there's shortcut key to move cursor from one sub window to another ?

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     +          +          +
+ G / +   F1     +    F2    +
+ r F +          +          +
+ o i +++++++++++++++++++++++
+ u l +          +          +
+ p e +   F3     +    F4    +
+     +          +          +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: even I don't know its answer I would like to know : how you divided it horizontally .. I am able to divide it vertically but not horizontally, using split option in top right corner of editor window.. is there any way to do horizontal split also?

Comment: Click the same split window button with option key together.

Answer (score 0):

To cycle through editor windows you can click `Cmd` + ` (backtick) [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415597/4981793)