# Is there a shortcut to switch between windows in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I do a lot of work on two projects at the same time and I was wondering if there was a keyboard shortcut, or a way to assign one in order switch between windows. This is currently done by going to the Window menu title and scrolling down, but I'm a shortcut man at heart!  I've tried going in to preferences, but it seems to be the only one you can't assign!

Comment: Have you tried Cmd-`?

Comment: That worked fine Greg, thank you very much!  If you put it as an answer I'll upvote you...

Comment: You could also change the accepted answer to @rdmacken's answer.

Comment: Or even @Guru's answer.

Comment: Have you try with `Cmd + ~`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I guess this has changed recently (I'm on XCode 6.1), but for anyone looking in it's now <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>. See [keyboard shortcut to switch project windows in xcode.](http://www.mackenziesoftware.com/2015/05/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-project-windows-in-XCode.html)

Comment: same in XCode 6.2 , use   cmd + ~

Comment: Still the same shortcut in Xcode 15.2. Brilliant!

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem some time ago. 
I solved this way: go in System Preferences of your Mac and choose Keyboard -> Shortcuts & Keyboard. There you find "Move focus to the next window" with a default shortcut.

[image]

In Xcode it will be this shortcut in conflict:

[image]

However, that shortcut is in conflict with Xcode, so you just need to modify either the Xcode or the system one :)

Comment: The other method mentioned below by Guru and Thomas is better. Use  CMD + ~

Comment: In the italian keyboard ~ is Alt+5. Moreover I still prefer the solution to have a unique global shortcut that does the same in Xcode as well as in any other program. Feel free to use the one you like!

Comment: Do not do this, checkout the other answers (Guru and and rdmacken mainly).

Comment: Nope, this answer worked for me. CMD+TILDE just beeps. I found the settings window (next time if possible please include english screenshots) and the default shortcut was CMD+SPACE, good enough for me.

Answer (score 23):

To switch between projects, use COMMAND + ~ (tilde)

Answer (score 3):

For more recent Xcode (i.e. Xcode 7 to at least Xcode 12), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36923255/6426003.

Basically `Command` + `~` still works unless the project is maximised.

To switch between maximized projects, use a **3-finger drag** left or right.

Answer (score 0):

To switch between TABS inside one project:

- Show previous TAB: <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>
- Show next: <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

[image]

It 100% works.

Comment: It's not like that, at least, not in the newest Xcode versions.

Comment: in Xcode 9.4 it works fine! Switch between windows INSIDE one project

Comment: I'm with 9.4.1 and I still didn't understand what you're saying. I opened many files of the same project and those shortcuts do nothing yet.

Comment: That is if you have opened multiple tabs at one window

Answer (score 0):

For xCode 13.0 the shortcut to switch between tabs is `CMD` + `Shift` + `]`.

Answer (score -1):

To switch between open windows => ⌘ + `

++++++
SOMEONE PUT A -1 ON MY SOLUTION BUT:

IT'S THE STANDARD FOR ALL APP WINDOWS
IN MACOS
++++++

Answer (score -4):

You can use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> as shortcuts.

Comment: Nah, these indent and re-indent lines.